# Custom vertical ScrollBar through half part of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar

I am trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

While I am aware of how to customize a ScrollBar, which can be achieved through shape drawables and styles and similarly the thumb, I am looking for an idea of how to place the scroll bar in between views on the left and right. any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Even a hint towards the right direction will do :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this going to work but maybe you can set you scroll bar view width to be very big (so it'll start from the list view edge and ended in the text view part).

But- I would recommend you to create a custom view for you scroll bar and implement it using scroll events on you list view, it'll be more flexible and you will be able to do things like dragging, change text size, etc...

Comment: I think the second approach will be feasible, how I think of that would be to create a drag-able view for the thumb and let the scrollbar be implemented in the list row itself. Sounds boggling a bit :D I am not sure if it is possible to drag a view across list rows.

Comment: No- you can't. You need to create a separate view that it's frame will be the whole screen and you need to set it's startY according to the list position.